# Python Split() - Optimum way to get multiple fields?

Tags: python

The data:

```
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
```

*Note: The data is really huge and random non-numbers actually, in real world.*

What I need:

```
field_two = 2
field_five = 5
```

What I've written:

```
field_two = data.split("|")[2]
field_five = data.split("|")[5]
```

Alternatively:

```
fields = data.split("|")
field_two = fields[2]
field_five = fields[5]
```

Can I make this better, faster, consume less memory and time in any way? What is the optimum way to get what I need?

Comment: Do you need only second and fifth elements?

Comment: @thefourtheye Maybe sixth too, but will that matter?

Comment: One-liner is straight-forward: `field_two, field_five = data.split("|")[2], data.split("|")[5]`. I don't think You'll save megabytes/hours here.

Comment: @Adobe yeah of course, not that.

Comment: @Adobe: `from operator import itemgetter` and `field_two, field_five = itemgetter(2, 5)(data.split('|'))`. Slightly tongue-in-cheek, but if the `itemgetter()` callable was stored in a local first, that'd by quite effective.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Please put it as an answer :) I can accept you! :) `itemgetter` sounds promising!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) here to extract multiple items:

```
from operator import itemgetter

items_2_and_5 = itemgetter(2, 5)

field_two, field_five = items_2_and_5(data.split('|', 6))
```

`itemgetter()` with multiple indices will return a tuple of values found at those indices:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> items_2_and_5 = itemgetter(2, 5)
>>> items_2_and_5(range(10))
(2, 5)
>>> items_2_and_5('hello world!')
('l', ' ')
```

The limit to `str.split()` makes the split more efficient as it won't have to do more work than you absolutely need.

For retrieving just two indices, this doesn't make much of a speed difference:

```
 $ bin/python -mtimeit -s 'data = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8"' 'fields = data.split("|", 6); field_two, field_five = data[2], data[5]'
 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.935 usec per loop
 $ bin/python -mtimeit -s 'data = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8"; from operator import itemgetter; items_2_and_5 = itemgetter(2, 5)' 'field_two, field_five = items_2_and_5(data.split("|", 6))'
 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.944 usec per loop
```

where .935 and .944 are too close to declare a winner. With *more* indices to retrieve the single function call will win out however:

```
$ bin/python -mtimeit -s 'data = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8"' 'fields = data.split("|", 6); field_two, field_four, field_five = data[2], data[4], data[5]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.935 usec per loop
$ bin/python -mtimeit -s 'data = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8"; from operator import itemgetter; items_2_4_and_5 = itemgetter(2, 4, 5)' 'field_two, field_four, field_five = items_2_4_and_5(data.split("|", 6))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.912 usec per loop
```

Comment: Just making sure before running some benchmarks, this would really improve performance, yeah?

Comment: @ComputerFellow: It *could* be faster; certainly when the number of indices retrieved goes up. You still have a function call (so there is a stack push and pop involved), which item access doesn't have to content with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only second and fifth elements, you can stop splitting like this

```
data = "0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8"
fields = data.split("|", 6)
field_two, field_five = data[2], data[5]
```

This reduces the computation as it stops splitting after splitting 6 times.

Comment: My main intention was to optimize the split call. This will split 6 columns anyway and store into fields. The data I have is huge.

Comment: But yeah this is a nice way to optimize at least a little bit! Upvoted! Thanks :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters That looks nice :) But how is that better than splitting till 6?

Comment: @thefourtheye: You can still limit the split count; it is an alternative to separating the split and the tuple assignment. I wasn't entirely serious; I find your version to be better because it is explicit and more readable over the `itemgetter()` trick. That's why I didn't post it as an answer instead.

Comment: `itemgetter(2, 5)(data.split('|', 6))` :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I upvoted yours :) I am still trying to understand other uses of `itemgetter`

Answer (score -1):

You can assign multiple variables at once (or, actually, simultaneously assign to a tuple of names):

```
field_two, field_five = data.split("|")[2:6:3]
```

This uses a slice on the list from `split` to extract the two values you need.

But the appropriate approach will depend on what you need the values for. Is there any reason you can't simply access the nth value using the index whenever needed?

```
>>> lst = data.split("|")
>>> lst[2]
'2'
```

This doesn't constrain you to picking the necessary names/values ahead of time.

Comment: Does this reduce computation and memory space or does it internally do the same thing is the verbose version?

Comment: The real world scenario is data is a 500 column line, and each line is occupies a lot of space which I don't want to waste in loading.

Comment: It only splits once, so would beat your first attempt in processing terms. However the slice creates a new list, and would use more memory than separately assigning the two items separately from the original list by index (your "alternative"). However, note that you have *already* loaded the whole line by the time you get to `split`. And 500 items isn't that many for modern computers!

Comment: Not sure I'd use a slice here; the readability suffers greatly for it.

Comment: I think that slicing is a bad solution because for more than 2 fields it will work only in a limited case when indices form arithmetic progression.

Comment: I agree with both of Martijn and volcano, but it works as a one-liner (which the OP requested but has edited out) for the specific case requested.